# Is there a server-side cursor on pure python based postgresql/redshift driver?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, pg8000

I am using `pg8000` package with Python 3 to query a table, and noticing the app memory consumption is growing as the table's record number grows which is now reaching over 16GB of memory consumption.

While inspecting cursor behaviour of `pg8000` package, I found the cursor cached the whole result set into an in-memory queue under `curr._cached_rows` property before being dequeued by any `.fetchone()`, `.fetchmany(n)` or `.fetchall()` methods.

In my specific case, I am extracting records on AWS Redshift by using Python shell on Glue job that comes with 2 restrictions:

1. No supports for Python's C based package (no `psycopg` unfortunately, which supports server-side cursor's cache)
2. Maximum of 16GB RAM.

I have gone through the `pg8000` documentation but couldn't find any reference to setting up server-side cursor. Is there anyway to setup server-side cursor on `pg8000` ? Or is there any other postgres/redshift pure Python package that supports server-side cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pg8000 docs now have [an example](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000#server-side-cursors) of server-side cursors:

```
>>> import pg8000.native
>>>
>>> con = pg8000.native.Connection(username, password="cpsnow")
>>> con.run("START TRANSACTION")
[]
>>> con.run("DECLARE c SCROLL CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM generate_series(1, 100)")
[]
>>> con.run("FETCH FORWARD 5 FROM c")
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
>>> con.run("MOVE FORWARD 50 FROM c")
[]
>>> con.run("FETCH BACKWARD 10 FROM c")
[[54], [53], [52], [51], [50], [49], [48], [47], [46], [45]]
>>> con.run("CLOSE c")
[]
>>> con.run("ROLLBACK")
[]
```